# How to read standard input from a Bash heredoc within a Groovy script

Tags: bash, groovy

I'm trying to make a Groovy script read standard input, so I can call it from a Bash script with a heredoc, but I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method readLine() on null object` exception.

Here's a cut-down Groovy script `echo.groovy`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
for (;;)
{
    String line = System.console().readLine()
    if (line == null)
        break
    println(">>> $line")
}
```

Here's the equivalent Ruby script `echo.rb`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
ARGF.each do |line|
  puts ">>> #{line}"
end
```

If I call these from a Bash shell, everything works as expected:

```
$ ./echo.rb 
one
>>> one
two
>>> two
three
>>> three
^C
$ ./echo.groovy 
one
>>> one
two
>>> two
three
>>> three
^C
```

This is the Bash script `heredoc.sh` using heredocs:

```
echo 'Calling echo.rb'
./echo.rb <<EOF
one
two
three
EOF
echo 'Calling echo.groovy'
./echo.groovy <<EOF
one
two
three
EOF
```

This is what happens when I run it:

```
$ ./heredoc.sh 
Calling echo.rb
>>> one
>>> two
>>> three
Calling echo.groovy
Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method readLine() on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method readLine() on null object
        at echo.run(echo.groovy:4)
```

Any ideas?

***UPDATE***

On Etan's advice, I changed `echo.groovy` to the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
for (;;)
{
    String line = reader.readLine()
    if (line == null)
        break
    println(">>> $line")
}
```

It now works with heredocs:

```
$ ./heredoc.sh 
Calling echo.rb
>>> one
>>> two
>>> three
Calling echo.groovy
>>> one
>>> two
>>> three
```

Thanks Etan.  If you'd like to post a formal answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: Ruby's `ARGF` reads from standard input.

System.console tries to read from the terminal (it just so happens that the terminal **is** standard input in a running terminal so `ARGF` works the way you expect here).

Find out how to read from standard input and not the terminal and I expect it will work in groovy. (Not posting as an answer as it isn't concrete and I only know how either of these things works because I did some quick searching online.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to Etan's answer, a Groovier approach is the `withReader` method, which handles the cleanup of the reader afterwards, and the BufferedReader's eachLine method, which handles the infinite looping.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

System.in.withReader { console ->
    console.eachLine { line ->
        println ">>> $line"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Etan says, you need to read from `System.in` I think this will get the response you are after

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
System.in.withReader { r ->
    r.eachLine { line ->
        println ">>> $line"
    }
}
```

Thought it's not exactly the same as the Ruby version, as `ARGF` will return arguments if any were passed